# To fetch unique Attribute/Column values in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

I have an Entity CalculatorProduct
with attributes as 'id','brand','category', 'mrp'
I want to fetch values only of 'category' column/attribute

```
  let context = DataBaseController.getContext()
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<CalculatorProduct> = CalculatorProduct.fetchRequest()

    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["category"]

    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
    do{

        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)


        print("array from db \(String(describing: result.count))")
        print("array from db \(String(describing: result))")

        for val in result{

            print("\(String(describing: val.category))")
        }

    }
    catch{

        print("error in fetching is\(error)")
    }
```

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: it is fetching whole object

Comment: i want values of column

Comment: Try with `fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
let context = DataBaseController.getContext()
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<CalculatorProduct> = CalculatorProduct.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["category"]
fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [[String:Any]]

    print("array from db \(String(describing: result.count))")
    print("array from db \(String(describing: result))")

    for val in result{
        print("\(String(describing: val["category"]))")
    }
}
catch{
    print("error in fetching is\(error)")
}
```

Comment: This won't work because the result you are excepting is CalculatorProduct so it will return the whole object, but actually, your code will give an error on "fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType" because you are trying to convert CalculatorProduct object to dictionary. So I just change "NSFetchRequest<CalculatorProduct>" to NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> , it worked for me.